# removing backtracking from an iterative regular expression

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I have to preface this by telling you that this regex is truly horrifying. I know this.

I am using regular expressions to match chunks of text while matching over whitespace and tags (like `<example>`). I use the following code to create the regular expression.

```
tag_re = r'(?:<[^>]*>)*\s*'
full_regex = '(' + tag_re + ''.join(
    itertools.chain(*zip(  
        map(re.escape, text_chunk),  
        itertools.cycle([tag_re])))) + ')'
full_regex = full_regex.replace(' ', ' ?')
```

This produces a regular expression that takes in a string and outputs that same string with `tag_re` interspersed between every single letter.
`test` would produce `t(?:<[^>]*>)*\s*e(?:<[^>]*>)*\s*s(?:<[^>]*>)*\s*t(?:<[^>]*>)*\s*`. this would match:

`test`, `t  est`, 
as well as a `test` with a line break somewhere.

The produced regex seems to hang on certain cases with large amounts of whitespace. I assume this is a backtracking issue, but I am not a regex expert and can't quite figure out how to solve this issue. the RE never hung before i added in the whitespace matching, it was fine with only the tag matching.

the data that it hangs on is below.

```
Iyvuldja MYA Nggsnjyxnlt Mlxunb


Iayd Dysoap Ysnatx,

Xsayra tlxa xwa haslq rjwaposap cyntxatytja yjxnenxv uld vlod Iyvuldja MYA yggsnjyxnlt wyr haat jlcgsaxap.


Xdlpojxnlt Ayntxatytja Qtuldcyxnlt

Njxnenxv:
Hjwaposap Ayntxatytja
Rayrlt:
Nggsnjyxnlt Mlxunb
Hxydx xnca:
Paptarpyv, 2 Ngdns 7942 - 7:99 NA (OT)
Otp xnca:
Paptarpyv, 2 Ngdns 7942 - 2:99 NA (OT)
Qcgyjx:Sradr qnss tlx ha yhsa xl slf ntxl xwa yggsnjyxnlt ld wyea yjjarr xl Pahjsljmr podntf xwa cyntxatytja qntplq.Nss hyjmfdlotp ilhr qnss ha xacgldydnsv gyorap.Twa JTX/HJTX radeadr qnss rxnss ha yeynsyhsa.Mydpqyda jsljmr qnss jltxntoa xl yjjagx gotjwar yr tldcys.
Yltxyjx:
Vlf nt xl xwa Yorxlcad Hoggldx Xldxys yx wxxgr://roggldx.pyvuldja.jlc .






*** FGTO: Xsayra pl tlx dagsv xl xwnr carryfa, yr xwa nthlb nr tlx cltnxldap.***

Qu vlo wyea ytv yppnxnltys koarxnltr ld dakonda roggldx uld vlod Iyvuldja MYA yggsnjyxnlt gsayra jltxyjx Yorxlcad Hoggldx orntf xwa Iyvuldja Hoggldx Xldxys yeynsyhsa yx roggldx.pyvuldja.jlc.











Twnr jlccotnjyxnlt nr ntxatpap xl ha dajaneap ltsv hv xwa ntpnenpoys[r] ld atxnxv[r] xl qwlc ld xl qwnjw nx nr yppdarrap, ytp jltxyntr ntuldcyxnlt qwnjw nr jltunpatxnys, gdnensafap ytp rohiajx xl jlgvdnfwx. Ntv otyoxwldnzap ora, jlgvntf, daenaq ld pnrjslroda nr gdlwnhnxap. Xsayra tlxnuv xwa ratpad nccapnyxasv nu vlo wyea dajaneap xwnr jlccotnjyxnlt nt addld [hv jyssntf jlssajx, nu tajarrydv] rl xwyx qa jyt yddytfa uld nxr daxodt yx lod abgatra. Thank you nt ypeytja uld vlod ytxnjngyxap yrrnrxytja ytp jllgadyxnlt.
Yaxxa jlccotnjyxnlt arx parxntea otnkoacatx a sy gadrltta lo a sy gadrltta cldysa a kon assa arx ypdarrea. Ossa jltxnatx pa sntuldcyxnlt jltunpatxnassa, gdlxefea gyd sa rajdax gdluarrnlttas ax roiaxxa a par pdlnxr p'yoxaodr. Tloxa oxnsnryxnlt, dagdlpojxnlt, jltrosxyxnlt lo pneosfyxnlt tlt yoxldnrear rltx ntxadpnxar. Flor elor gdnltr pyenrad nccepnyxacatx sabgepnxaod rn elor yeaz daco jaxxa jlccotnjyxnlt gyd addaod (at yggasytx a udynr ender, rn tejarrynda), yunt koa tlor gonrrnltr gdatpda par pnrglrnxnltr glod at yrrodad sa dateln a tlr udynr. Flor elor dacadjnltr a syeytja pa elxda jllgedyxnlt.
```

Comment: Could you provide a string that causes issues? Or, I guess, these are string with several repeated consecutive characters and not matching strings.

Comment: added the string. I can't give the whole data getting searched through as it's too large. but if you just create random data around the given data, it should give the same result.

Comment: No way, I can't think of a solution.

Comment: I've realized now that the issue is coming from  `full_regex = full_regex.replace(' ', ' ?')`. I am attempting to figure out why a simple optional space is creating such an issue, but so far haven't been successful.

Comment: Check the actual requirements, maybe a work around is through tweaking them instead of the regex.